# Minimize already open program with command in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, command-line

Is there any Command I can use to minimize the certain open programs in windows 10?

Comment: Please clarify your question as currently it's vague. You can easily minimize any program by clicking the minimize icon on the title bar of the program or by using the keyboard shortcut `Win+Down arrow`, however if you want to minimize specific programs, you could write a script to do that, what research have you done so far?

Comment: I want to make a simple .bat file which can minimize already open program

Comment: Windows-M (as in "minimize") usually does the trick.

Comment: EDIT: forgot the command line, sorry. You can add the "/minimize" switch or argument at the end of your command, but first, you have to "pass" the program in question to CLI. That's the rub: in a simple command line window, I don't think you can do that, but you can script something as PS's "Get-focus"?

Answer (score 0):

Please see this program [NirCmd](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html)

It can do what you want, but you will have to identify the program by name or class. Example:

```
Minimize all your Internet Explorer windows
nircmd.exe win min class "IEFrame"
```

Alternatives include [AHK](https://www.autohotkey.com/) [Powershell](https://gist.github.com/lalibi/3762289efc5805f8cfcf)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, what will be an MS word document class

Comment: You can search for windowspy and use it to find out. Or just use the title of the window. Word?

Answer (score 0):

As Vijay mentioned, this is rather trivial with [WinMinimize](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinMinimize.htm) and related commands in AutoHotkey, but you could also interact with the Windows API directly via [SendMessage](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessage) / [WM_SYSCOMMAND](https://docs.micro), in the language of your choice. If by "command" you mean a shell like cmd.exe, then no, I'm not aware of a native executable that would accomplish this.